# Join two tables and get number of rows

Tags: mysql

I need to get the number of **posts** not topics, where forum_id = 1. Is this even possible? I guess I have to use join but this seems incredible hard for me.

```
topics:
id | title | forum_id

posts:
id | message | topic_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts JOIN topics t ON (topic_id = t.id) WHERE forum_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

number of posts with  a topic

```
 select distinct count(p.id) from posts p inner join topics t on p.topic_id = t.id 
        where t.forum_id = 1
        group by p.id
```